# How to implement bubble sort?

Tags: c++, bubble-sort

I have to write a program that takes in 10 integers then displays them. Then displays them in reverse order. Lastly displays them in ascending order. Here is what I have so far. I am stuck on the last part (sorting); everything else works fine.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    
    int a[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
    {
        cout << "Enter a number\n ";
        cin >> a[i];
    }
    
    cout << "Array Reversed\n";
    for (int i = 9; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        cout << a[i] << " ";
    }
    
    cout << "Numbers from lowest to highest\n";
    for (int i = a[i]; i != 0; i = i/10 )
    {
        i % 10;
        cout << i << " ";
    }
    
}
```

Comment: This needs to have some kind of sort actually happening. Start by writing a `sort` function of some kind that takes an array and size pair of arguments, or better, a `std::vector` as you should do in C++.

Comment: Or `std::array`

Comment: And `std::sort`.

Comment: Also, notice that the line `i % 10;` has no effect!

Comment: Is the goal here to *write a Bubble Sort function* or to just have them sorted?

Comment: @cigien I guess this is a part of a homework assignment, thus, using `std::sort` isn't a valid solution.

Comment: @Kerek Maybe so, but OP hasn't indicated that. I's rather they know about `sort` first. If they can't use it, that's fine too.

Comment: @tadman yes I was going for bubble sort but unfortunately, I am having to teach myself c++ luckily with some java knowledge and I am burnt out trying to research everything with the little I can find. I have been stuck on this for the past hour. My professor doesn't give us any notes, textbooks or lecture videos to help teach us

Comment: The harsh truth is that most C++ courses, by virtue of their "professors", are absolute junk and are just something you need to survive without ending up too damaged. C++ is a fantastic yet extremely unforgiving language, it's not something you can intuitively figure out, so you'll need a good [reference book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) to refer to when you need answers to questions like this.

Comment: @Kerek yes in the assinment it says to try something like bubble sorting. I have watched a bunch of videos and looked up some examples and can't seem to tie it into this code

Comment: Whenever you're faced with an algorithm problem check Wikipedia for a reference first. Like here [Bubble Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) is explained with pseudo-code, something you can use as a start for your C++ version.

Comment: @cyber_cloud *I am having to teach myself c++ luckily with some java knowledge* -- Pretend that Java does not exist when learning C++.  If you use Java as a model in learning or writing C++, all you'll end up with are buggy programs, inefficient programs, or programs that look weird to a C++ programmer.

Comment: The difference between an *ascending* sort and a *descending* sort is the comparison function between two elements.  If your code for *ascending* sort works, copy it and then change the comparison operator.

Comment: @Thomas: I'm not sure a descending sort is needed here. The assignment calls for entry order, reverse entry order, and ascending order.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie *or programs that look weird to a C++ programmer.* This may not matter. Odds are tragically high that the professor isn't a C++ programmer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need a bubble sort, the general idea is (pseudo-code):

```
# The array to sort.

arr = [3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9]

# Initially assume sorting needs a pass.

hasSwapped = true
while hasSwapped:
    # If nothing swapped in this pass, we're done.

    hasSwapped = false

    # Check each element except last.

    for idx = 0 to arr.sz - 2 inclusive:
        # If bigger than next element, swap, flag another pass needed.

        if arr[idx] > arr[idx + 1]:
            temp = arr[idx]
            arr[idx] = arr[idx + 1]
            arr[idx + 1] = temp
            hasSwapped = true
```

You should hopefully be able to understand the intent from the comments but the basic idea is:

- A single pass will check all elements and, if one is greater than the one after it, it will swap them.
- You have to do at least *one* pass.
- If a pass completes without a swap, the data is now sorted. Otherwise, more passes are needed.

Your job is now to convert that to the language of your choice.

---

I'll include an implementation below, with the function itself in C (though it will also work in C++, as evidenced by the surrounding test harness).

However, you would be unwise to assume educators don't perform plagiarism checks on assignments they give. In other words, *don't* use this code as-is, you'll almost certainly be caught out. Its intent is just to show you a possible implementation that you can compare your own code to:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void bubbleSort(int *arr, size_t sz) {
    int hasSwapped = 1;
    while (hasSwapped) {
        hasSwapped = 0;
        for (size_t idx = 0; idx < sz - 1; ++idx) {
            if (arr[idx] > arr[idx + 1]) {
                int temp = arr[idx];
                arr[idx] = arr[idx + 1];
                arr[idx + 1] = temp;
                hasSwapped = 1;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    int arr[] = { 3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9, 2, 6, 5, 3, 5, 9 };

    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(arr) / sizeof(*arr); ++i)
        cout << arr[i] << ' ';
    cout << '\n';

    bubbleSort(arr, sizeof(arr) / sizeof(*arr));

    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(arr) / sizeof(*arr); ++i)
        cout << arr[i] << ' ';
    cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The output is, as expected:

```
3 1 4 1 5 9 2 6 5 3 5 9
1 1 2 3 3 4 5 5 5 6 9 9
```